# PHP MySQL encoding issue with XML

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am dealing with a third-party XML which contains special characters like bullets, long dashes etc.

Sample XML:

```
$xml = "<xml><node>• Special Characters</node></xml>";
```

My goal is to parse this XML using PHP and insert it in a MySQL database. I am using `DomDocument` to parse the XML to get a `SimpleXMLElement` object from the DOM node using `simplexml_import_dom`.

The load method of `DomDocument` fails unless I use utf8_encode to encode the xml.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(utf8_encode($xml));
```

To be able to parse the xml, I understand that I need the `utf8_encode` function. After being able to parse the XML, the inserts in MySQL table will result in special characters appearing as ? or garbage. Even the special characters from XML if displayed on a browser after parsing will be garbage.

The MySQL table column is of text datatype and is in latin1_swedish_ci collation. I saw similar questions on SO and tried their solutions like running `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8')` or changing the column encoding but they didn't work for me.

Please advise.

Comment: Where does `$xml` come from and whar makes you think you need `utf8_encode()`?

Comment: Do you have any idea of the encoding of your xml? 
Your table must be on utf8 too.

Comment: Have you tried setting the DB collation to `utf8_general_ci` or something?

Comment: The xml comes as http post request. without the utf8_encode, the DomDocument is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your database only works with Latin1 encoding by default.  You'll want to change your database or table (I forget which, maybe both) encoding to UTF8.

You could try

```
alter table TABLE_NAME charset utf8
```

http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/convert-mysql-db-to-utf8